# How to shows data after XML Parsing if the file contains CADATA in XML file?

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing, cdata, android-parser

I'm new to Android Development, I have to parse my XML files through Http request, i'm using this example for parsing

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

which works fine for me in all the the XML file through HTTPRequest except the one which having CADATA like:-

```
<title> <![CDATA[ Timer for work ]]> </title>
```

When i'm trying to parse this file which having this type of data i'm not getting any thing on the ListView. 
This file having 10 new after parsing it shows only 10 cells but not showing any data but when i parse other XML file which not having this kind of CADATA type data that works fine showing text .

Can any one plz suggest me how to rectify this problem of CADATA in parsing XML.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to know [that `LexicalHandler`s](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/sax.html#gcxhb) exist. You get callbacks of `startCDATA()` `endCDATA()`

Comment: Hi Reno can you please give some example or code which display CDATA on the ListView i'm new to Android can find any solution which solve my problem i read about DocumentFactory and KSOP2 but not able to solve this problem please give some sample code for this problem for displaying CDATA which sample code is more beneficial for me Thanks